# Google Analytics bounce rate

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, seo

I have a bounce rate of almost 90% on my site, I'm wondering if it has to do with my setup perhaps google doesn't like it?

My site contains multiple filters you can choose and I want them stacked nicely like this in the url:
/banana/kitchen/workspace/
or
/kitchen/banana/workspace/
or
/workspace/kitchen/banana/
etc

So the users can select the filter in any order they want and I don't have to worry about making all links order the filters correctly.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ redirs.php?data=$0 [QSA]
```

Could this make google think all these suburls are one and the same? In redirs.php I use include() to fetch the correct page based on what's inside the url.

-

**Background info:**

I was running into a situation where .htaccess was looking something like this **before**:

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/banana/ banana.php
RewriteRule ^/banana/kitchen/ banana.php?location=kitchen
RewriteRule ^/kitchen/banana/ banana.php?location=kitchen
RewriteRule ^/banana/kitchen/ banana.php?location=kitchen
RewriteRule ^/kitchen/banana/orange banana.php?location=kitchen&orange
RewriteRule ^/orange/kitchen/banana/ banana.php?location=kitchen&orange
RewriteRule ^/banana/orange/kitchen/ banana.php?location=kitchen&orange
```

etc..

I use a canonical meta tags don't worry about duplicate content for these..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytics.js runs on the client, so all that matters is the final URL that appears in the browser. It's very unlikely that your issue has anything to do with your .htaccess file.

It's much more likely that your bounce rate is high for other reasons. I'd highly recommend reading this article on [How Google Analytics calculates time](http://cutroni.com/blog/2012/02/29/understanding-google-analytics-time-calculations/). It will probably shed some light on your bounce rate issue.